# React native web will not compile with linear gradient

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux

Using react native web linear gradient and I can not run npm build web to build the final product due to this error. I have the latest version of linear gradient and react.

```
./node_modules/react-native-linear-gradient/index.android.js

import { processColor, StyleSheet, View } from 'react-native';
import NativeLinearGradient, { type Props } from './common';
const convertPoint = (name, point) => {
```

Comment: what's the error?

Comment: Oh sorry that wasnt clear, wrote that post in the middle of the night. The error was in index.android.js and " { type props } " was just underlined in the file. The terminal said that there should be a comma in type props? Seems like this package is broken. Here is a link to the issue on GitHub https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-linear-gradient/issues/377 .